# REACT NATIVE - Firebase Android e-commerce events not fired with Google Tag Manager

Tags: react-native, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

we are working on a React Native app that implements various [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) modules.
The plugin implementation was done correctly, as we could see the various events on the Firebase console. However, once the Google Tag Manager library was also implemented, we began to notice a decrease in the number of event logs related to ecommerce on the Android platform. Investigating the cause we started debugging from Android, where we can see that the payload is always sent via the javascript layer and we do not see any errors on the logcat, except this one which seems related to the GTM implementation:

`{ "tag": "GoogleTagManager", "pid": 6305, "tid": 6377, "message": "Internal error - Function call: __fm_sendFirebaseEvent\nInvalid param type for key 'items'. Only boolean, double and string types and maps of thereof are supported.", "date": "2023-09-15T07:20:21.436Z", "type": "error", "count": 1 }`

This issue is not present on the iOS version of our App.

As we deactivate GTM implementation we're able to see e-commerce events on Firebase DebugView.

We also already opened an [issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/7350) where you can find all the information on our implementation.

Has anybody faced the same problem and found a solution? Any known workaround?

Thanks.

We already updated the plugin and the library to last version, we've also opened an issue on the plugin project github.